# LINQ Error: Method not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using the following code which compiles without problems but I am getting this error when I call the method:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllCitiesOfCountry(int id)
    {
        var ad = from a in entities.Addresses
                 where a.CountryID == id
                 select a.City.Distinct().ToString();
        var fa = from b in entities.FacilityAddresses
                 where b.CountryID == id
                 select b.City.Distinct().ToString();
        return ad.Concat(fa).Distinct();
    }
```

How can it be re-written in order to work?

Comment: What is the type of the `City` properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type is `City`?  If it's already a string, just drop the `.Distinct().ToString()` calls.  If it's a complex type, select out the city name from the type.

**Update**: based on your comment, you should drop the Distint() and ToString() calls. The final Union over the collections of city names should give you unique city names.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllCitiesOfCountry(int id) 
{ 
    var ad = from a in entities.Addresses 
             where a.CountryID == id 
             select a.City;
    var fa = from b in entities.FacilityAddresses 
             where b.CountryID == id 
             select b.City;
    return ad.Union(fa);
}
```

Comment: +1. And if it's a string, what are you doing calling `Distinct` on it?

Comment: City is string but if I drop the ToString() I get a conversion error from <char> to <string> at the return .Concat()

Comment: @Stripling - absolutely right, if it's a string you don't need either the Distinct or the ToString calls.  I've updated based the comments.

Comment: Now I think about it more, I'll bet he meant to have the `Distinct` get applied to the whole query, rather than to the `City`. But since he's calling `Distinct` after the `Concat`, there's no point.

Comment: @tvanfosson Thanks it works. Is there any difference between using concat() or Union()?

Comment: @Stripling That's exactly what I meant to do but this is basically the first time I'm trying to write code... You can expect a lot more stupid mistakes/questions from me :D

Comment: @Tsarl - yes, now that I think about it. Union would be more appropriate.  Union produces the set union, without duplicates.  Concat merely appends the second to the first.  Union would be equivalent to Concat(x).Distinct().

Answer (score 4):

Update - I think this is what you are looking for

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllCitiesOfCountry(int id)
    {
        var ad = from a in entities.Addresses
                 where a.CountryID == id
                 select a.City;
        var fa = from b in entities.FacilityAddresses
                 where b.CountryID == id
                 select b.City;
        return ad.Union(fa).Distinct();
    }
```